# jquery dialog open only first time

Tags: php, javascript

I have jquery dialog and when i click over the button it open but only first time when i close it and click second time over the same button it not appears. Here is my code :

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialogPicture").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });    

    $(".buttonClass").on("click", function () {

        // get the div element with the id dialogClass contained at the same scope as button!    

        var id = ($(this).siblings(".dialogClass").attr("id"));
        $("#" + id).dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $("#" + id).dialog("open").css({
            "font-size": "13px"
        });    
    });    
});
```

HTML :

```
<td>
   <?=$row['NOMER']?><input id="btn2" class="buttonClass" type="button" value="ВИЖ" />
   <div class="dialogClass" id="dialogPicture_<?=$row['NOMER'];?>" style="display:none;">
      <table class="bilet">
         <tr>
            <h2>
               <td colspan="4">
                  <div align="center"><strong>ПРЕВОЗЕН БИЛЕТ</strong></div>
               </td>
            </h2>
         </tr>
         <p>
            <tr >
         <td colspan="2" align="right">
      </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: what about $("#" + id).dialog();

Comment: this for every row  of table to open dialog with different information

Comment: i mean did you try $("#" + id).dialog(); without any parameter in dialog

Comment: yes but it did not work

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no there is no error in console

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this.

You should use this Code to destroy the Dialog  in Button Section

```
   $("#TestMenuDialog").dialog("close").dialog("destroy").remove();

 var NewDialog = $('<div id="TestMenuDialog"><p style="color:Red;style="font-size:7x;font-weight:normal">' + Message + '</p></div>');
        NewDialog.dialog({
            modal: false,
            title: "Test Dialog",
            height: 200,
            width: 375,
            show: 'clip',
            hide: 'clip',
            buttons: [
                  { text: "OK", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close").dialog("destroy").remove(); } }
            ]
        });
```

check the Jfiddle Link It works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/zpP3c/1/

Comment: ok but how i can fit this to my code? Sorry i am new in jquery

Comment: Try this One... in click event of button, it shouldn't have any issue, Please let me know, because we have to destroy the Dialog after the Dialog, so taht they can regenerate the Dailog again

Comment: is just Variable to Hold some string... thats all

Comment: If you don't mind, Can u just Create jsfiddle link for this, Or else I will create the same

Comment: My target is : for each row i have a button and when i click the button to show a differnet information i tried to destroy dialog in button section but it works only when i clicked for first time after refresh after that it does not work

Comment: Can u Please Update with fiddle link, without this, How can I tell you the issue ?

Comment: This works exactly i want to but where i must put my div with information?

Comment: If it resloved Makes as an Answer, Or If any issues Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that on each button click you create a new instance of dialog box.
Try initializing all the dialog boxes in the beginning of the script and let the buttons only open them.
Another issue is that the dialog div is no longer on the table after initialization:
`<div id="btn<?=$row['NOMER']?>"`.....

```
        $(function () {
            $(".dialogClass").each(function(){
                $(this).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
            }); 

                $(".buttonClass").on("click", function () {

                // get the div element with the id dialogClass contained at the same scope as button!    

                var btnId = ($(this).attr("id"));
                btnId = btnId.replace("btn","");
                $("#dialogPicture_" + btnId).dialog("open").css({
                    "font-size": "13px"
                });    
            });   
        });
```

Comment: try this: $(".dialogClass").each(function(){$(this).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});});

Comment: aaa! now I can see the problem. After initializing of the dialogs they are no longer in the table. you can see it in the current element structure. I changed my answer accordingly. You can choose different logic to identify the button with the dialog

Comment: could you help me please?